# Disable mouse wheel while animation plays

Tags: javascript, scroll, mousewheel, gsap

I'm trying to achive the effect that on scroll down/up GSAP animation will play and change the section content and after it reches the last section it will display first section content and so on if scroll up on first content it display last content, but the eventListener is added on wheel, because I want to prevent page scroll, and here is the problem. If you scroll while the animation is playing it will display wrong content and if you scroll too many times the incrementation / decrementation will brake the code, so my question is: can I disable mouse wheel on a time when the animation is playing? Tried to use preventDefault() on event, but it didn't work at all.

```
let tl = gsap.timeline();
let sections = document.getElementsByTagName('section');
let i = 0;

document.addEventListener('wheel', e => {
  if (checkUp(e) && i > 0) {
    console.log('UP');
    anim();
    setTimeout(up, 2000);
    console.log(i);
  } 
  else if (!(checkUp(e)) && i < 2) {
    console.log('Down');
    anim();
    setTimeout(down, 2000);
    console.log(i);
  }
  else if (!(checkUp(e)) && i === 2) {
    anim();
    setTimeout(last, 2000);
  }
  else if (checkUp(e) && i === 0) {
    anim();
    setTimeout(first, 2000);
  }
});


checkUp = (e) => {
    if (e.wheelDelta) {
      return e.wheelDelta > 0;
    }
    return e.deltaY < 0;
  } 

down = () => {
    sections[i].className = '';
    i++;
    sections[i].className = 'active';
}

up = () => {
    sections[i].className = '';
    i--;
    sections[i].className = 'active';
}

last = () => {
    sections[i].className = '';
    sections[0].className = 'active';
    i=0;
}

first = () => {
    sections[i].className = '';
    sections[2].className = 'active';
    i=2;
}

anim = () => {
    tl
        .to('section', 2, {opacity: 0})
        .to('section', 2, {opacity: 1});
}
```

Also I'm sorry if the solution is kinda messed up, but this was the only thing that came to my mind

**CODEPEN** [codepen link](https://codepen.io/voitb/pen/JjGvwNx)

Comment: Can you use promise based timelines .then(). You could define a global/window variable is_animating.  Use if is_animating in your wheel listener before anything else. https://greensock.com/forums/topic/22288-gsap-3-and-promises/

Comment: It doesn't really solve my problem, because if i scroll again while animation is playing, then animation will play once again and again, as many times as the wheel was detected. [codepen](https://codepen.io/voitb/pen/GRoGjZK?editors=0010)

Comment: I was saying put logic in your wheel detection function  to “do nothing” if animation is playing otherwise play an animation

Comment: This has been [answered on the GreenSock forums](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/24760-disable-mouse-wheel-while-animation-plays/) for reference.